# No data available in table issues of laravel yajra/laravel-datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am using https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/ package 
to show data within html table via ajax request and here is my settings

**route**

```
   Route::get('dashboard/initiation-by-org', ['uses' =>'DashboardController@showTotalInitiationByOrganization']);
```

**controller**

```
public function showTotalInitiationByOrganization(){
    $litigation = collect(Dashboard::countLitigationsOfAnOrganizationByCountry());
    return Datatables::of($litigation)->make(true);
}
```

**call data table**

```
 $('#organization-cases').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            aaSorting: [],
            iDisplayLength: 6,
            iDisplayStart: 0,
            ajax: '/dashboard/initiation-by-org',
            "columns": [
                {'data': 'organization'},
                {'data': 'litigations'}
            ]
        });

**My json response**


 {
          "draw": 0,
          "recordsTotal": 2,
          "recordsFiltered": 2,
          "data": [
            {
              "organization": "Shakti Samuha",
              "litigations": 1
            },
            {
              "organization": "CWIN",
              "litigations": 1
            }
          ],
          "input": [

          ]
        }
```

**my table**

```
 <table id="organization-cases" class="table table-bordeard">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Organization</th>
       <th>Litigations</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I have install this package according to the installation manual but I did not get any data in my table.
please tell me What is the problem of this issue?

Thanks
Manoz

Comment: Is that response data in your Question from seeing the table query your PHP endpoint or is it from manually navigating to it?  If it didn't come from your browser's development tools please open that and confirm that the data table is making a request to the server.  Then you can inspect what is being sent and what is received by the DataTable library.  Also you have that "input" attribute at the end of your JSON I am not sure if that could be causing you trouble.  DataTables can be finicky around the response parsing.